# how to get a list of file names from a given path in pike

Tags: file, path, pike

I have a project in school using pike language.
I've never used it before and I have a question:
How do I get a list of file names from a given path?

For example:
How do I get all the files in `C:\Users\Downloads`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_dir()` function for this task. Read more about it [here](http://pike.lysator.liu.se/generated/manual/modref/ex/predef_3A_3A/get_dir.html). In general Pike has fairly ok documentation under above url.